# Where does Firebase fit in?

Tags: javascript, programming-languages, programming-practices, html5

I am a front-end developer who is familiar with HTML, CSS, JS and to a degree, AngularJS.

I've chanced upon [Firebase (firebase.google.com)](https://firebase.google.com/) - and was wondering if I could, with my lack of knowledge with server-side code, use Firebase for my app.

Will I need to learn JSON for this?

Comment: Familiarity isn't going to get this done.  Yes, you'll need to learn JSON.  You also need to read up on Firebase and shore up your existing skills.

Comment: @RobertHarvey - Let me rephrase that: Could I use Firebase if I learnt JSON - but not PHP, SQL and so on? I'm a beginner, sorry for the possibly trivial nature of this question.

Comment: you can use firebase with javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since Firebase offers a full JS API, there is no need to learn an additional language like PHP. You can access data there as if were stored in JavaScript objects.

It is intentionally built to made it easier for folks comfortable with client-side programming and less comfortable with server-side.